# Input box alerts the text by clicking a button (Really new to JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

#### JQuery Part

I just started using JQuery. First I wanted to create a a input box with an button that alerts the text that is in that box. This is the way I wanted to do that.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#hit').click(function() { 
    alert($('#term').val());
  });
});
```

That is the code in the html body part. Here im not sure if I have to declare the id with an # or not. I tried both but It didnt work for both.

#### My Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Button Event</title>
      <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> $(document).ready(function() { $('#hit').click(function() { alert($('#term').val()); }); }); </script> 
   </head>
   <body> <input id="term" type="text" value="enter your search"> <button id="hit" type="button" name="Button">Search</button> </body>
</html>
```

I am really new to JavaScript and Jquery. When I run this code there are no errors or something like that in the console just blank. The Button and Input field are on the website but when I enter something and click the button after that nothing happens. That´s why im sure there are some mistakes in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#hit').click(function() { 
    alert($('#term').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="term" type="text" value="enter your search" />
    <button id="hit" type="button" name="Button">Search</button>
```

here has worked, do you have imported a jquery library?

Resolution with your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Button Event</title>
   </head>
   <body> <input id="term" type="text" value="enter your search"> <button id="hit" type="button" name="Button">Search</button>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() { $('#hit').click(function() { alert($('#term').val()); }); });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wasn´t able to import it with an hosted version thats why I downloaded it. That is how I added it.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"src="jquery-3.6.0.js">

Comment: can you see the console and send error here?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: your script is in the page or separated file?

Comment: same file thats the entire code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Button Event</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hit').click(function() {
      alert($('#term').val());
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="term" type="text" value="enter your search">
    <button id="hit" type="button" name="Button">Search</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: so let me explain to you, you put script inside jquery import declaration, you can't do this.
the right one is: create a new script tag just to your script. this gonna solve your problems.

Comment: i've edited my answer, if this help you mark as solved;